# SQL Server : Executing Procedure Using IF on Scalar

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, common-table-expression, execute

I have a query that compares values in two columns, row by row, and sums the `ABS(diff)` to a single scalar `int`. I want to use the final scalar `int` to determine if a procedure should be executed.

The query has two `WITH` and a single `SELECT FROM` the 2nd `WITH` like this:

```
WITH AAA AS (...),    
BBB AS (... FROM AAA)    
SELECT SUM(I)    
FROM BBB
```

The query works - I get the correct result when it's run as `SELECT`.

However, when I try to use an `IF [result] = 0`, I get syntax errors no matter where I put the `IF` condition.

Is there any way to combine `WITH` and `IF` in the way I want?

EDIT:

```
WITH AAA AS 
(
    SELECT 
        OrderNo, ItemNo, QuantityOrdered, 
        SUM(QuantityDelivered) AS Delivered
    FROM 
        GGG
    WHERE 
        OrderNo = 12345
),
BBB AS 
(
    SELECT 
        OrderNo, ABS(SUM(QuantityOrdered) - SUM(Deleivered)) AS Diff
    FROM 
        AAA
)
SELECT SUM(Diff) AS Diffsum
FROM BBB

IF Diffsum <> 0 Execute...
```

I tried:

```
DECLARE @Intdiff INTEGER;

SET @Intdiff = (

WITH ...etc
```

but I get:

> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried. You've question is unclear here, especially as we only have the concept of a query in your question, not the actual query.

Comment: I have tried IF ((query) <> 0) EXECUTE [procedure] as well as putting the IF before the SELECT FROM BBB - all yield syntax.

Comment: Question unclear

Comment: Again, that doesn't really help. `IF ((Select 1) <> 0) EXECUTE [MyProc];` works fine. You need be be **much** clearer here.

Comment: WITH AAA AS (SELECT OrderNo, ItemNo, QuantityOrdered, SUM(QuantityDelivered) AS Delivered
FROM GGG
WHERE OrderNo = 12345),
BBB AS (SELECT OrderNo, ABS(SUM(QuantityOrdered) - SUM(Deleivered)) AS Diff
FROM AAA)

SELECT SUM(Diff) AS Diffsum
FROM BBB

IF Diffsum <> 0 Execute...

Comment: `Diffsum` is a column name of your query result. I imagine that to use it the way you are trying to, you would need to assign it to a variable. So if you know your query only returns a single result you could do something like `@diffsum = WITH....` (or maybe `@diffsum = SELECT SUM(Diff)...`) and then `IF @diffsum <> 0 ...`. You would also need to declare `@diffsum` first.

Answer (score 0):

Hardly an answer, as you are almost there, just have a few bits in the wrong place.  This should work?

```
--Declare a variable
DECLARE @DiffSum INT;

--Set the value based on a query
WITH AAA AS 
(
    SELECT 
        OrderNo, 
        ItemNo, 
        QuantityOrdered, 
        SUM(QuantityDelivered) AS Delivered
    FROM 
        GGG
    WHERE 
        OrderNo = 12345
),
BBB AS 
(
    SELECT 
        OrderNo, 
        ABS(SUM(QuantityOrdered) - SUM(Deleivered)) AS Diff
    FROM 
        AAA
)
SELECT @DiffSum = SUM(Diff) FROM BBB;

--Execute a stored procedure based on the result
IF @Diffsum <> 0 EXECUTE ...
```